# HTML Form Action Java

Tags: java, html, url, forms

I have a java program which I want to input something into an `html form`. If possible it could just load a url like this

```
.../html_form_action.asp?kill=Kill+Server
```

But i'm not sure how to load a url in Java. How would I do this? Or is there a better way to send an action to an `html form`?

Comment: `I want to input something into an html form` can you show us the code ?

Comment: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your security, you can make an `HTTP` call in `Java`. It is often referred to as a RESTFul call. The `HttpURLConnection` class offers `encapsulation` for basic GET/POST requests. There is also an `HttpClient` from `Apache`.

Comment: Is there documentation on the encapsulation? I tried java.net.URLConnection connection = new URL(url + "?" + query).openConnection(); but that didn't send the request. Should it have?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can use [URLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) to send a simple HTTP request.

```
URL url = new URL(url + "?" + query);

// set connection properties
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");

connection.connect(); // send request

// read response
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
     System.out.println(line);
}

reader.close(); // close connection
```